# Should a proxy overwrite the Domain part of a cookie

Tags: python, http, session-cookies

I'm currently building a pass-through proxy in python, using requests.
This is rather a HTTP question, nevertheless.

One of the sites I'm testing the application with, sets a cookie that has an established domain, which, if sent as-is to the client, doesn't allow it to resend this cookie on successive requests (this is a session cookie).

Should I overwrite this part of the cookie with my own domain? Or is there a header I can set for this? I've tried setting: X-Forwarded-Host and X-Forwarded-Port with no luck